# how to create Snapshot & Release Folder for Artifactory using CI pipeline?

Tags: sbt, gitlab-ci, artifactory, python-wheel

I want to create snapshot & release folder in Jfrog Artifactory using CI Pipeline while doing deployment in Gitlab.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: The repositories must be created, when the pipeline executes, these objects must go to your repository. But alas, they must be created.

Answer (score 2):

JFrog Artifactory uses repositories for storing and managing artifacts. One repository usually contains many artifacts. In general, repositories are usually created once, not during a CI run.

[Maven repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Repository) can be configured to host releases, snapshots or both. The common practice is to create a [local repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Local+Repositories) for snapshots (e.g. `libs-snapshot-local`) and a local repository for releases (e.g. `libs-release-local`). In addition, you can add [remote repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Remote+Repositories) (e.g. for proxying Maven Central). On top of that you can add [virtual repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Virtual+Repositories) - to aggregate several repositories.

Please refer to the following links to get more information:

- Screencast: [Setting Up A Maven Repository With JFrog Artifactory In Less Than One Minute](https://jfrog.com/screencast/setting-maven-repository-jfrog-artifactory-less-one-minute/)
- Official Documentation: [Maven Repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Repository)
- QuickStart Guide: [Maven and Gradle](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/QuickStart+Guide%3A+Maven+and+Gradle)